# What is the closest waypoint to Urzael?

Tags: diablo-iii

I don't remember Act V all that well and I've done a bunch of Google searching that tells me all about the location Urzael is in and details about the fight, but all I really need to know is where the closest waypoint is so that I can get there without walking through every part of the first half of Act V.

Comment: Since at least version 2.3 there is an icon for each boss on Act maps. You can see where who is and if they are still alive in the current game.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Urzael is near `Westmarch Heights` Waypoint in Act V.